# How to get <a> innerText based on class name?

Tags: javascript

Say I have: `<a class="helloh" id="helloh">return this value</a>`

Basically I want to get the innerText of `<a>` tag based on class name.

The problem is when I try: `alert(document.getElementsByClassName("helloh").innerText);` it return `undefined` but when I try: `alert(document.getElementById("helloh").innerText);` it return me they actual value that I want.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of elements. Try outputting it to the console to take a look for yourself. If you do `alert(document.getElementsByClassName("helloh")[0].innerText);` you'll get what you're expecting. For future reference - use `console.log` to debug your code (it will display in browser's console)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `document.getElementsByClassName("helloh")[0].innerText` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("helloh").innerText`. 
When using `getElementsByClassName`, you will get array of elements instead of single array unlike `getElementById`.

Comment: What If you have more Anchor elements? Hard-coding index value doesn't seem a good idea in real scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

A new syntax version is `document.querySelector()` which will return the first matching element. It saves you having to do `getElementsByClassName('name')[0]`

From the following:

```
<a class="helloh" id="helloh">get by ID</a>

<a class="helloh2" id="helloh2">get by Class</a>
```

You can use:

```
// by ID
console.log(document.querySelector('#helloh').innerText)

// by Class
console.log(document.querySelector('.helloh2').innerText)
```

If you want multiple elements, you can use `document.querySelectorAll()`:

```
<a class="helloh" id="helloh">get by ID</a>

<a class="helloh" id="helloh2">get by Class</a>

// get both by Class
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.helloh'))
```

Notice the `#` and `.`

You specify classes with `.`, IDs by `#`, and omit both to search by block elements .

For example, `document.querySelectorAll('div')` will return all divs on the page.

You can also use multiple at the same time:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div .helloh #helloh2')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("helloh")[0].textContent;
alert(a);
```

```html
<a class="helloh" id="helloh">return this value</a>
```